# Where should I put the requests related to excel export/import on Graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have an architectural doubt.

I am using the GraphQL as an API provider and I need to develop some API requests to import data from excel and to export data to excel on my project.

Where should I create this using the GraphQL API?

I researched and discovered it is possible to create customized `queries` and `mutations` on the GraphQL... In this case...

- This should be a `query`?
- This should be a `mutation`?
- Or other thing?

**Side note**: I am using the GraphQL API on my Ruby on Rails project via the `graphql-ruby` gem and I am also using the `mongoid` gem to deal with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing to REST API this is how it should be

<kbd>`REST`</kbd>                      <kbd>`GrapQL`</kbd>         
<kbd>`GET`</kbd>                       <kbd>`GrapQL Query`</kbd>   
<kbd>`POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE`</kbd>  <kbd>`GrapQL Mutation`</kbd>

If you are just querying go for GraphQL Query
If you are modifying the data use Mutations

In your case import should be mutation whereas export can be query

Read more - [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations)

Comment: I really suspected that the answer would be that! Great and simple answer. Thank you! :D